# pass bash config file as argument

Tags: bash

I am trying to pass a `config` file asan argument from the command line to a script and not getting the expected results.
Thank you :).

config called on command line as:

```
bash script.sh /path/to/config.txt
```

**contents of /path/to/config.txt**

```
#File1comment
var1=/path/to/file1
#File2comment
var2=/path/to/file2
```

**contents of script.sh**

```
config=$1

. $config

echo -e "$@"
test -n "$1" && set -- a b c
```

**current**

```
/path/to/config.txt
```

**desired**   --- each file avaliable to script ---

```
/path/to/file2
/path/to/file2
```

**new code**

```
config=$1

set -- $config
echo -e "$@"
while read line; do
  printf "$line" >script.sh
done <"$config"
```

Comment: Why aren't you printing `$var1` and `$var2` in your script?

Comment: so I just need to `printf` after the `set` to print each line in `config`? Thank you :).

Comment: I added a `new code` to the post that if I just print the `$line, I do see each `var` printed. However when I re-direct it to the script I do not see them. Are they avaliable to the script to use? Thank you :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit unclear what you want or need to do with your configuration file.

If your configuration file is a file that you wish to source in your script, as you do in one of you examples, then the code in the file name by `$config` will be executed.

Executing the code in the file name in `$config` sets the two variables `var1` and `var2`.  To use their values, use `$var1` and `$var2` in the script.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

config=$1

. $config

printf 'var1 is %s\n' "$var1"
printf 'var2 is %s\n' "$var2"
```

If you instead want to parse out the strings after the `=` characters in the file pointed to by `$config`, then you would probably *not* source the file, and instead use `sed` like so:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

config=$1

sed -n '/^#/d; /[^=]*=/s///p' "$config"
```

The `sed` command in this script ignores any lines that start with a `#` character or that does not contain a `=` character.  For every other line, the first `=` character on the line and all that precedes it is removed and the remaining data is printed.

Comment: Thank you very much :)